# How can I update a list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a text File where I want to copy every line into a list like that:

textfile:

```
ID: 6795237870698427 USDT/VET
ID: 5105294695113172 USDT/SOL
ID: 8739424619942096 USDT/ICP
```

list:

```
[
    {'ID': 6795237870698427, 'symbol': 'USDT/VET'},
    {'ID': 5105294695113172, 'symbol': 'USDT/SOL'},
    {'ID': 8739424619942096, 'symbol': 'USDT/ICP'}
]
```

This already works like this:

```
line_count = len(open('var_share.txt').readlines(  ))
ides = open('var_share.txt').readlines(  )
list.clear()
for i in ides:
    id = i[4:20]
    pos1 = i.find('/')
    symbol = i[(pos1-10):(pos1+10)]
    pos2 = symbol.find(' ')
    symbol = symbol[pos2+1:]
    pos3 = symbol.find('\n')
    symbol = symbol[:pos3]
    list.append({'ID': id, 'symbol': str(symbol), 'status': False})
```

The Problem now is that the list gets cleared every time I update the list and this is a problem because the value of the status variable gets changed.
To solve this I tried to look into the list if the item already exists using the ID before adding it.

Code:

```
found = False
line_count = len(open('var_share.txt').readlines(  ))
ides = open('var_share.txt').readlines(  )
for i in ides:
    id = i[4:20]
    pos1 = i.find('/')
    symbol = i[(pos1-10):(pos1+10)]
    pos2 = symbol.find(' ')
    symbol = symbol[pos2+1:]
    pos3 = symbol.find('\n')
    symbol = symbol[:pos3]
    for e in list:
        if(e['symbol'] == symbol and found == False):
            found = True
        else:
            found = False
    if(found == False):
        list.append({'ID': id, 'symbol': str(symbol)})
```

Comment: Why a list? If you used a dictionary, with the `ID` value as key, you can map each to the symbol.

Comment: You can look at the `defaultdict` data-structure present in the `collections` module in python which will allow you to map multiple symbols to the same key by creating a list of symbols and map it to the key according to the text file.

Comment: please resist using a reserved word like `list` as a variable name

Comment: what exactly do you mean by updating list and your code doesn't show how status variable changes and found is independent of status

Comment: It is unclear what your goal is and where your "list" (please rename this variable) is maintained between "updates".